# Splunk String Search

Tags: powershell, splunk

I have a powershell command value for a process field that I am trying to match in my splunk search but I am getting
*"Error in 'SearchParser': Subsearches are only valid as arguments to commands. Error at position '3271' of search query 'litsearch (index=notable ((sourcetype="WMI:LocalPr...{snipped} {errorcontext = andLine"=[[Decoded Ba}'."*:

```
`macro` rule_name="rule-name" process="[[Decoded Base64]] -LogName Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational 
| Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 100 -and $_.TimeCreated -ge ((Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 90))} 
| Format-list ;<!LF!>$ImpersonatedUser.ImpersonationContext.Undo()<!LF!>"
```

I need a solution for grabbing every instance that this value occurs

Comment: what's the script that's trying to run this? You've got unmatched quote marks in what you've already provided. How are you accessing Splunk with Powershell?

Comment: I'm not accessing splunk with powershell.  This is a search query for powershell commands

Comment: This sounds like a vendor-software-specific "how do I" question that should be addressed to the vendor.

Comment: What does your event data look like?